# wkhtmltopdf not supporting data uri

Tags: php, javascript, html, wkhtmltopdf

I have created a report generating library for my project using php DOMDocument to create html file and save as temporary file. Html includes javascript part that takes parameter and renders a shape using canvas and saves as data URI, but it shows blank in pdf.

```
    <div style="width:100%;height:200px">
              <img id="overview" style="width:170px;height:170px;float:left;padding:10px" 
src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAADICAYAAACtWK6eAAAcxklEQVR4nO2deXhU5b3HXxattba4UVu
        XinVp771Pe3uLXW5re6OXyg3n/Z0Qda56W1t722JrXUq1rbZUpwUVympgCEPCJCEJS0ggJAGEbMiWEJJAco0
    57wkhIJhl9swSWXPuH5nEEZLZZ37nTN7P83yep545pnPe3/fnmbO9hxBOXGhPT7+pXRCmywCPMkp/L4GwmIGQIwEtY5QeZEAlBkKXDNQuA7UzoB4GVPHp+Xi50MWASozSgzKl2yWgJgmExYzS38sAj7YLw
    vS2mTNvxN5eDmdUTojiLbIo/oiJwku+BmhiQF1+YU+Q4Bz6/xZyGK/l9OEGcfT0z+PPT6ccURtSsrkdkGYLoHwOxmgiAE9k/hGCNszMkCRDMLz7YIwvTYlZTL2OHKSiOOieI8k0hcloLsv+xmkVT0M6A4m0ueOi+I92OPL0Ri
    K...+i6PWTsevHSSCSKN4qUzovVnuVZHpIylVTc86an7/bsmrVN7HrxEFGIWRCB6X/LlO6ggE9E2mDaP0hKU9d3UX75s1N5tWrfqYQMgG7LhwVouj1E2Vx1g8ZCMuYSFk4DaLFh6TctbVnrYWFDX0
    GwzNKbS3/CcUJj+OieA8T6XMM6A4W4C2+WnlIynP48KBj+/ZuS37+ZktWVgr2+HKSCEWnmyTPmvWNobNhwgYG9IPhBlHrQ1LuffsuOMq2n7IWFpb0ZmY+oRiNV2GPI2ccwQBu
    ZpT+56k/vrzQXlwsOXftcnnq6y4lfM/Q0DDo3LPHY9taIls3Fpb3ZWf/kV+n4KgWW8ai2y1r1/7YnJX1ljk3p9haWHDIVlIiOysqep2Vla7+6uqz7v37z3sOHx70NjcPXhH6lhbF09Aw6D5w4IKrtuass7LS1b9
    rV5+jtLTDtmlTvTU/b6vFZFpsXrfu6b5c4/iatzaB/D/Az73HHWzt/AAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">
            </div>
```

javascript part

```
 var angle=360-((relate/(relate+download))*360);
can=document.createElement("canvas");
    can.width=200;
can.height=200;
ctx=can.getContext("2d");
var centerx=can.width/2;
var centery=can.width/2;
ctx.fillStyle="#d94d4c";
ctx.strokeStyle="#d94d4c";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(centerx,centery,(can.width/2)-40,0,2*Math.PI,false);
ctx.arc(centerx,centery,can.width/2,2*Math.PI,0,true);
ctx.fill();
ctx.fillStyle="#f6d2d2";
ctx.strokeStyle="#f6d2d2";
if(angle>=60){
    angle=angle-60
}else{
    angle=angle+300
}
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(centerx,centery,(can.width/2)-40,300*(Math.PI/180),angle*(Math.PI/180),false);
ctx.arc(centerx,centery,can.width/2,angle*(Math.PI/180),300*(Math.PI/180),true);
ctx.fill();
document.getElementById(relateid).src=can.toDataURL();
```

What may be the problem?

Comment: Can you post some sample javascript so I can try to reproduce this?

Comment: Sorry for late edit... please refer the javascript part..

Comment: Did you find an answer for this? I ran into the same problem with a Ruby on Rails application.